# How can I make my C# calculator run as intended

Tags: c#, calculator

I have a C# calculator I'm trying to get to run however I keep running into problems, particularly with my last function and currently get stuck in an infinite validation loop, how can I make this work as intended which is to take two numbers and based on user input get the answer for their equation.

```
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello User what is your name?");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Hello " + name + " Please enter in a number");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a Math Operator: +, -, *, / ");
            string beta = IsValidSymbol();
            string equation = Console.ReadLine();
            string useint1 = Console.ReadLine();
            string useint2 = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Please  enter another number");
            Console.WriteLine(MathSymbols(equation,useint1,useint2));
        }

        public static double Validation()
        {
            string numbString = Console.ReadLine();
            double numbVerify;
            while (!double.TryParse(numbString, out numbVerify))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("please only enter in numbers and do not leave blank");
                numbString = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            return numbVerify;
        }
        private static string IsValidSymbol()
        {
            string mathValidation = Console.ReadLine();
            while ((String.IsNullOrEmpty(mathValidation)))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please, do not leave the sentence field empty!");
                Console.WriteLine("Enter a Math Operator: +, -, *, / ");
                mathValidation = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            return mathValidation;
        }
        private static double MathSymbols(string e, string useint1,string useint2)
        {
            useint1 = Console.ReadLine();
            useint2 = Console.ReadLine();
            double result;
            double userinput1;
            double userinput2;
            while (!double.TryParse(useint1, out userinput1))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("please type in a number");
                useint1 = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            while (!double.TryParse(useint2, out userinput2))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("please type in a number");
                useint1 = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            if (e == "+")
            {
                result = userinput1 + userinput2;
            }
            else if (e == "-")
            {
                result = userinput1 - userinput2;
            }
            else if (e == "*")
            {
                result = (userinput1 * userinput2);
            }
            else if (e == "/")
            {
                result = (userinput1 / userinput2);
            }
            result = 0;
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm going to assume you're new to programming, on your method ```MathSymbols``` ```useint1``` and ```useint2``` are already defined and as such the ```Console.ReadLine()``` is overkill. that is for getting user values which after you have it is kept in memory on the variable. If it is you're first crack at programming, I would recommend you find an article that explains the basics of OOP, it'll be the best thing you can do for yourself.

Comment: yes it is my first crack at it thank you for the advice I'll definitely look into that.

Answer (score 1):

In many places you had an unnecessary call to `Console.ReadLine` and overriding variables. Also you didn't use your method `Validation` (think about renaming it to `GetValidNumber`).

I corrected your code to work for valid input. You still need additional validations and refactoring in your code, good luck!

```
using System;

namespace CalculatorExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello User what is your name?");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Hello " + name + " Please enter in a number");
            double useint1 = Validation();

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a Math Operator: +, -, *, / ");
            string equation = IsValidSymbol();
            Console.WriteLine($"You equation symbol: {equation}");

            Console.WriteLine("Please  enter another number");
            double useint2 = Validation();

            double result = MathSymbols(equation, useint1, useint2);
            Console.WriteLine($"Result: {result}");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static double Validation()
        {
            string numbString = Console.ReadLine();
            double numbVerify;
            while (!double.TryParse(numbString, out numbVerify))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("please only enter in numbers and do not leave blank");
                numbString = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            return numbVerify;
        }
        private static string IsValidSymbol()
        {
            string mathValidation = Console.ReadLine();
            while ((String.IsNullOrEmpty(mathValidation)))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please, do not leave the sentence field empty!");
                Console.WriteLine("Enter a Math Operator: +, -, *, / ");
                mathValidation = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            return mathValidation;
        }
        private static double MathSymbols(string equation, double useint1, double useint2)
        {
            if (equation == "+")
               return useint1 + useint2;
            if (equation == "-")
               return useint1 - useint2;
            if (equation == "*")
                return useint1 * useint2;
            if (equation == "/")
                return useint1 / useint2;

            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Unrecognized equation symbol: {equation}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for the help I really appreciate it